# How to decompile pyinstaller executable file to get Python code

Tags: python

Accidentally deleted the python code, all i have is a single ***unix executable*** file generate by pyinstaller.
Is there a way to reverse this and to extract my code ?

Comment: "Your code"? Not if you expect comments/formatting/etc. Your pyinstaller executable contains Python bytecode -- which is an easy-to-reverse format, but it _isn't_ your original source.

Comment: When I last needed to do this, I wrote https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller. YMMV, if it breaks you get to keep both pieces, etc. That said, my personal use case for it _does_ include pyinstaller executables built with Linux as a target, so it's definitely not Windows-specific.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for giving me some light, could you please give the commands to use your utility. Couldn't execute using the instructions in How Do I Use It section of git

Comment: able to list contents, but in extract getting below error  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/satya/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xdis/load.py", line 199, in load_module_from_file_object
    float_version = magic_int2float(magic_int)
  File "/Users/satya/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xdis/magics.py", line 426, in magic_int2float
    return py_str2float(magicint2version[magic_int])
KeyError: 227
`